# react redux reducer not changin

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

I got this insane problem that I think has more to do about pure JS rather than redux.

My initial state looks like this:

```
let data = {
    outputs : ["0", "0", "0", "0"],
    analogIn : "0"
}
```

and this is part of my reducer so when I try to change a value of the outputs array (e.g. the 3rd value)

```
let newstate = Object.assign({}, state);
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CLICK_OUTPUT':
            let outputs = newstate.outputs
            let status = outputs[action.num]
            let newStatus = (status == "0") ? "1" : "0"
            outputs[action.num] = newStatus
            newstate.outputs = outputs
            console.log(newstate.outputs[action.num])    <-- 1.
            console.log(newstate.outputs)                <-- 2. 
            console.log(newstate)                        <-- 3.
            return newstate
        default:
            return state || data.data
}
```

1. Returns "1" which is correct
2. Returns ["0", "0", "1", "0"] which is correct
3. Returns

   analogIn : "0",
     outputs : ["0", "0", "0", "0"]

so the state is not changed...

When I try to change the analogIn it works

```
case 'CHANGE_IN':
    newstate.analogIn = action.val
    return newstate
```

Any ideas why does this happen?
Does it have to do with redux?

Comment: The problem is somewhere in your wider application, the reducer above as a pure function works fine. http://jsbin.com/wuqidefujo/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the solution.

As it seems using this:

```
newstate.outputs = outputs
```

or this:

```
newstate.outputs[num] = "1"
```

does not work if you want to copy the contents of one array to the value of an object that is an array

The solution was to clone the array

```
newstate.outputs = outputs.slice(0)
```

I'm not sure if this occured because of es6 or it is pure JS.